# Alamofire return status code issue on swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I am using alamofire to handle http request but I found that alamofire only accept a range of http response status code beteween 200 to 299. Is there any way to customize the acceptable status code? Below is the code I added with a customized return code range but it doesn't work. The response code is 10050. Could you let me know whether I miss anything here?

```
 let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10 // seconds
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
            let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
       manager.request(.POST, "http://localhost:880/login", 
            parameters:["mobile" : mobile, "password" : password],
            encoding: .URL)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<50000)
            .response(queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), completionHandler: {
                (request, response, data, error ) in
                completeHandler(data, response, error)

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire only accept a range of http status code in the [**Automatic Validation**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#automatic-validation) within `200...299` range, like in this code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .validate()
     .responseJSON { response in
         switch response.result {
         case .Success:
             print("Validation Successful")
         case .Failure(let error):
             print(error)
         }
     }
```

But you can include in the [**Manual Validation**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manual-validation) the range you want and it works very well:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://realm.io/")
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .Success(let value):
                print(value)
            case .Failure( _):

                guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else { return }
                print(statusCode)
            }
    }
```

This address returns an `403` error from my country and works very well using Alamofire, even if don't want to validate and handle yourself:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://realm.io/").responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .Success(let value):
            print(value)
        case .Failure( _):

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else { return }
            print(statusCode)
        }
    }
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I just tried with manual validation but it doesn't seem to work. I have updated my post and added my code there. Could you let me know what I missed here?